# Мобильная клавиатура перекрывает поле ввода

Tags: javascript, reactjs, telegram, web-apps

Сайт открывает в Telegram Web App. Когда пытался делать сдвиг(с помощью js) при нажатие на input ничего не работало.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте почему-то всё работало
*всё работает на react